# SEO Team in a fix

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

I am getting a educational website developed by dedicated developers. I have a SEO team as well.

We are working on the SEO and SEM for past six months and were able to get our keywords ranked in top pages. But since the latest panda update by google all our keywords went down. We researched a lot to get around but couldn't get the right direction.

None of blogs gave any emphatic suggestion. Our SEO team is in a complete fix. Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Comment: what is your website?

I didn't have an issue with googles release with any of my sites. Were you link farming?

Comment: no we are not doing any blahhat seo techniques....

Comment: @alfasin i have asked the same there as well....but no replies. I think its a much less active group.

Comment: and waited 20 mins ? :) be patient, give it a day or two. It may be less active, but the community in webmasters will be able to provide answers for questions on this topic.

Comment: @alfasin hm...ok. M sorry.

Comment: If you want people to respond, I'd strongly suggest modifying the title of your question to reflect the actual problem.

Comment: How did you "optimize" your keywords?